# Client Certificate authentication without local truststore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

OK, this might sound strange at first, so please bear with me :-)

The problem I need to solve is this:
I need to enable client authentication in a Spring Boot application in a way, that allows the client to create the certificate themselves, *without* the need for the server to sign the CSR with the servers private key.

How can I achieve this goal?

---

Background: Why do I need this?

We have setup a Spring Cloud Config Server. It contains the configuration values for many different applications. We now want to allow each application access only to its own configuration values.
The easiest - yet secure - solution to this problem seems to be the following:

1. The application creates a self signed certificate
2. It stores the certificate including its private key on the server it runs on and sets the access control so that only its service user has access to it
3. It tries to request its configuration values from the Cloud Config Server.
4. It will fail, because the client certificate is unknown to the server
5. The application will log an error with the URL it tried to reach and the public key of its certificate
6. An admin user will manually create a mapping between the URL and the public key in a secure configuration storage that the Cloud Config Server can read
7. Now, when the application tries to read its config values from the server, the server will look into its secure configuration storage and check if their is an entry for the requested URL and if so, if the request was signed with the private key that matches the public key that was stored for that URL.
8. If all succeeds, the configuration values are returned

Point 7 will be implemented as a simple `Filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I want to achieve basically boils down to one issue:
Instead of loading the truststore from a file, the truststore has to be created in-memory, based on data from the secure configuration storage.
This turned out to be a bit tricky, but absolutely possible.

Creating a truststore is easy:

```
KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ts.load(null);

for (Certificate cert : certList) {
    ts.setCertificateEntry(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), cert);
}
```

However, supplying it to the SSL processing pipeline is a bit tricky. Basically, what we need to do is to provide an implementation of `X509ExtendedTrustManager` that uses the truststore that we created above.
To make this implementation known to the SSL processing pipeline, we need to implement our own provider:

```
public class ReloadableTrustManagerProvider extends Provider {
    public ReloadableTrustManagerProvider() {
        super("ReloadableTrustManager", 1, "Provider to load client certificates from memory");
        put("TrustManagerFactory." + TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(), ReloadableTrustManagerFactory.class.getName());
    }
}
```

This provider in turn uses a `TrustManagerFactorySpi` implementation:

```
public class ReloadableTrustManagerFactory extends TrustManagerFactorySpi {

    private final TrustManagerFactory originalTrustManagerFactory;

    public ReloadableTrustManagerFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        ProviderList originalProviders = ProviderList.newList(
                Arrays.stream(Security.getProviders()).filter(p -> p.getClass() != ReloadableTrustManagerProvider.class)
                        .toArray(Provider[]::new));

        Provider.Service service = originalProviders.getService("TrustManagerFactory", TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        originalTrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(), service.getProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineInit(KeyStore keyStore) throws KeyStoreException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineInit(ManagerFactoryParameters managerFactoryParameters) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    }

    @Override
    protected TrustManager[] engineGetTrustManagers() {
        try {
            return new TrustManager[]{new ReloadableX509TrustManager(originalTrustManagerFactory)};
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new TrustManager[0];
        }
    }
}
```

More about `originalTrustManagerFactory` and `ReloadableX509TrustManager` later.
Finally, we need to register the provider in a way that makes it the default one, so that the SSL pipeline will use it:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new ReloadableTrustManagerProvider(), 1);
```

This code can be execute in `main`, before `SpringApplication.run`.

To recap: We need to insert our provider into the list of security providers. Our provider uses our own trust manager factory to create instances of our own trust manager.

Two things are still missing:

1. The implementation of our trust manager
2. The explanation for `originalTrustManagerFactory`

First, the implementation (based on https://donneyfan.com/blog/dynamic-java-truststore-for-a-jax-ws-client):

```
public class ReloadableX509TrustManager extends X509ExtendedTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private final TrustManagerFactory originalTrustManagerFactory;
    private X509ExtendedTrustManager clientCertsTrustManager;
    private X509ExtendedTrustManager serverCertsTrustManager;
    private ArrayList<Certificate> certList;
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ReloadableX509TrustManager.class);

    public ReloadableX509TrustManager(TrustManagerFactory originalTrustManagerFactory) throws Exception {
        try {
            this.originalTrustManagerFactory = originalTrustManagerFactory;
            certList = new ArrayList<>();
            /* Example on how to load and add a certificate. Instead of loading it here, it should be loaded externally and added via addCertificates
            // Should get from secure configuration store
            String cert64 = "base64 encoded certificate";
            byte encodedCert[] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cert64);
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedCert));
            certList.add(cert); */
            reloadTrustManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.fatal(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes a certificate from the pending list. Automatically reloads the TrustManager
     *
     * @param cert is not null and was already added
     * @throws Exception if cannot be reloaded
     */
    public void removeCertificate(Certificate cert) throws Exception {
        certList.remove(cert);
        reloadTrustManager();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a list of certificates to the manager. Automatically reloads the TrustManager
     *
     * @param certs is not null
     * @throws Exception if cannot be reloaded
     */
    public void addCertificates(List<Certificate> certs) throws Exception {
        certList.addAll(certs);
        reloadTrustManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        clientCertsTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        clientCertsTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s, socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        clientCertsTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(x509Certificates, s, sslEngine);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        serverCertsTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) throws CertificateException {
        serverCertsTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s, socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) throws CertificateException {
        serverCertsTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(x509Certificates, s, sslEngine);
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return ArrayUtils.addAll(serverCertsTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers(), clientCertsTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers());
    }

    private void reloadTrustManager() throws Exception {
        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ts.load(null);

        for (Certificate cert : certList) {
            ts.setCertificateEntry(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), cert);
        }

        clientCertsTrustManager = getTrustManager(ts);
        serverCertsTrustManager = getTrustManager(null);
    }

    private X509ExtendedTrustManager getTrustManager(KeyStore ts) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        originalTrustManagerFactory.init(ts);
        TrustManager tms[] = originalTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
            if (tms[i] instanceof X509ExtendedTrustManager) {
                return (X509ExtendedTrustManager) tms[i];
            }
        }

        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("No X509TrustManager in TrustManagerFactory");
    }
}
```

This implementation has a few notable points:

1. It actually delegates all work to the normal default trust manager. To be able to obtain it, we need to have the default trust manager factory that would normally be used by the SSL pipeline. That's why we pass it as the parameter `originalTrustManagerFactory` in the constructor.
2. We are actually using two different trust manager instances: One for validating client certificates - which is used when a client sends a request to us and authenticates itself with a client certificate - and another one for validating server certificates - which is used when we send a request to a server using HTTPS. For validating the client certificates, we create a trust manager with our own truststore. This will contain only the certificates that are stored in our secure configuration store and therefore it will not contain any of the root CAs that Java usually trusts. If we would use this trust manager for requests to a HTTPS URL where we are the client, the request would fail as we would be unable to verify the validity of the server's certificate. Therefore, the trust manager for the server certificate validation is created without passing a truststore and will therefore use the default Java truststore.
3. `getAcceptedIssuers` needs to return the accepted issuers from both our trust managers, because in this method we don't know if the certificate validation is happening for a client or a server certificate. This has the small drawback that our trustmanager would also trust servers which are using our self signed client certificates for their HTTPS.

To make all of this work, we need to enable ssl client authentication:

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keyStore.p12 # secures our API with SSL. Needed, to enable client certificates handling
server.ssl.key-store-password: very-secure
server.ssl.client-auth: need
```

Because we are creating our own truststore, we don't need the setting `server.ssl.trust-store` and its related settings

Comment: Hi, I have implemented your solution to have an in memory trust store. But can you give an example as to how to do I add a certificate to trust store during run time? Say when a GET endpoint is invoked

Comment: I have also a bounty open here regarding the same question, sad that I did not come across your solution before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143673/spring-boot-how-to-update-truststore-dynamically/57183801?noredirect=1#comment100904567_57183801

Comment: you can post the answer here and link this post in the answer to my bounty post. I would gladly accept your answer with much appreciation.

Comment: What's the issue? Whenever you add or remove a certificate, the trust store is reloaded

Comment: I get my certificate as a base64 encoded string. If i create a new instance of `ReloadableX509TrustManager` and call addCertificates method. It does not affect the actual trust store

Comment: Don't create a new instance. Add the certificate to the existing instance. Better yet: Create a service with an observable to which you can add the certificate. Subscribe to the observable in the Reloadable trust manager and update it when a new value comes through the observable

Comment: How do i get access to the existing instance? Could you please show me how? You can post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143673/spring-boot-how-to-update-truststore-dynamically/57183801#57183801 so that I will be able to accept and award the bounty

Comment: Can you please help me?