# Subscribe weakly to Observable

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a class whose instances are being created by Java (via [`GetInstance`](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~malenkov/8022746.8.1/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/jca/GetInstance.java.html)).
The class subscribes to an observable in its constructor.
I have no control over the lifetime of the instances and I also have no way of knowing when an instance is no longer needed, so I can't just unsubscribe.
Because of the subscription to the observable, my instances are never garbage collected.

Therefore, I would like to subscribe to the observable in a way that does not prevent garbage collection.
Is it possible?

Here is what I tried, but I am unsure how to verify that it actually does what it is supposed to do:

```
class WeakConsumer implements Consumer<ObsType> {
    private final WeakReference<MyType> ref;
    public WeakConsumer(WeakReference<MyType> ref) { this.ref = ref; }

    @Override
    public void accept(ObsType value) throws Exception {
        MyType instance = ref.get();
        if(instance != null) { 
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

And in the class `MyType`:

```
obs.subscribe(new WeakConsumer(new WeakReference<>(this)));
```

Will this work as expected?

Comment: This may allow your (real) consumers to be garbage collected but you still have the `WeakConsumer` instances.

Comment: Good point. I see two solutions: Unsubscribe next time `accept` is called and `instance` is `null` or override finalize in my real consumer and unsubscribe there. What do you think?

Comment: If the instances do not unsubscribe, and the observable does not complete, why do you want them to be garbage collected? They are still working. If you need not their work, then just do not create them.

Comment: As I said, I have no influence on their lifecycle. They get created by the runtime. As long as the runtime uses them, they need data from the observables. But when the runtime no longer needs them, they should be garbage collected.

Comment: What is runtime? Why runtime does not order the subscribers to unsubscribe when it does not need them anymore? How do you know the moment when runtime  no longer needs them? Can you replace the class of subscribers with it extention?

Comment: The runtime is the SSL engine that handles a SSL connection. My class is a security provider and registered in a way so that the engine uses it to verify client and server certificates (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847579/client-certificate-authentication-without-local-truststore/56864631#56864631). The SSL engine doesn't know about the implementation details of my class and the security provider contract contains no notion of a close / release / finish, so there is no info for my class to unsubscribe